# Multiple archives on front page in Wordpres

Tags: php, wordpress, archive, frontpage

can someone help me with this code.
I want to display multiple archives on my front page.

I have custom archives - "archive-gemer.php" and "archive-spis.php".
My page is currently set to "Your homepage displays Your homepage displays Your latest posts".
I would like to see the content from both archives on the main page.

I tried to create something like this:
(function.php)

```
function ql_is_front_page( $query = null ) {
    if ( ! $query ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $query = $wp_query;
    }
    $front_page_id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
    return (bool) $front_page_id === (bool) $query->get_queried_object_id();
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_custom_front_page' );
function my_custom_front_page() {
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ql_set_as_front_page' );
}

function ql_set_as_front_page( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ql_is_front_page( $query ) ) {
        $query->set( 'page_id', '' );
        $query->is_page = false;
        $query->is_singular = false;
        
        if ( $query->is_post_type_archive( array( 'gemer', 'spis' ) ) ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'gemer', 'spis' ) );
            $query->is_archive = true;
            $query->is_post_type_archive = true;

            ob_start();
            include( 'archive-gemer.php' );
            $archive_gemer_content = ob_get_clean();

            ob_start();
            include( 'archive-spis.php' );
            $archive_spis_content = ob_get_clean();

            echo '<div class="content-select-regions">' . $archive_gemer_content . $archive_spis_content . '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

on front-page.php

```
<?php get_template_part( 'archive', 'gemer' ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'archive', 'spis' ); ?>
```

archive-gemer.php

```
<h1>Gemer Content</h1>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div>
      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

archive-spis.php

```
<h1>Spis Content</h1>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div>
      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, on the main page it only prints HTML tags, but nothing from wordpress.

Can someone help me how to set in function.php so that both archives are listed?

Thank you for answear.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Output buffering _inside_ `pre_get_posts` to generate HTML code, and then even _outputting_ that code from within that filter callback ... that _can't_ make any sense, IMHO.

Comment: Other than that you are using a different h1 headline, the code of both of your archive templates there appears to be identical to begin with. So it would make much more sense to modify the front page query to include posts from both types, sorted _by_ type first - and then use _one_ template (the actual front page template), that implements what is known as a _control break_, to output the correct h1 in the correct places.